# Как поместить input[type="radio"] + label в DIV контейнер?

Tags: css, form

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с CSS: http://codepen.io/michael-e/pen/aOOzLP

Так стиль работает:

**input[type="radio"] + label {}**

Так нет (отсутствует правая граница у последней кнопки):

**.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"] + label {}**

```css
@import url(http://reset5.googlecode.com/hg/reset.min.css);

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
  border-right: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px 0px
}

.generic-radio-box label:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
}

.generic-radio-box label:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}

.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="generic-radio-box">
  <input type="radio" name="gsm-operator" id="r1">
  <label for="r1"><span>МТС</span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="gsm-operator" id="r2" checked>
  <label for="r2"><span>Билайн</span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="gsm-operator" id="r3">
  <label for="r3"><span>Мегафон</span></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fhzbt9en/

так?

```css
.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #BCBCBC; 
  border-left: none;  
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}
.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"] + label:nth-of-type(1){
    border-left: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
}
.generic-radio-box label:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.generic-radio-box input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="generic-radio-box">
  <input type="radio" name="gsm-operator" id="r1">
  <label for="r1"><span>МТС</span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="gsm-operator" id="r2" checked>
  <label for="r2"><span>Билайн</span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="gsm-operator" id="r3">
  <label for="r3"><span>Мегафон</span></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Работает.
Спасибо, большое )